# How to define a flag with default value for a library?

Tags: c++

I Implemented the following function in separate `matrix.h` and `matrix.cpp` files :

```
void calc ( double* a, double* b, int r, int c, double (*f) (double) )
```

Parameters **a**, **r**, **c** and **f** are input and **b** is output. **a** and **b** are 2d matrices with **r** rows and **c** 
columns. **f** is a function pointer which can point to any function of the following type :

```
double function‐name ( double x ) { 
    … 
}
```

Function `calc` converts every element in matrix **a**, i.e., aij, to bij=f(aij) in matrix **b**.

Now I want to convert the source code into a static library called **matrix.a** .

But I want this library  to contain  a  Boolean  value  named **do_round**  also, which  is  set  to  false  by  default.  When 
do_round is true, bij is set to bij = round ( f(aij) ).

Hoe can I do it? I mean I must do it in a way that in cases that the user not defined this variable in its program or defined it and not assigned any value to it (i.e. not initialized it) or defined it and assign a value of true/false to it, my program works fine. What shall I do?

This is my *matrix.cpp* contents :

```
void  calc(double* a,double* b,int r,int c ,double (*f) (double) )
{
    double input;
    double output;

    for(int i=0;i<r*c;i++)
    {
        input=a[i];
        output=(*f)(input);
        b[i]=output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a `static` global variable in the source file, and a function to set the value of it?

Comment: Why do you allow the user to define the Boolean variable that is used by your library?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Source file of my library or the user program? if you meant the user program, I can't, I have access to my library only.

Comment: @Lingxi How can I restrict him/her?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg moreover, I can't want him to call another function in his program! he only call my `calc` function, with the same arguments and not anymore. (The program is written already and the user[teacher] wants me to implement the library for it)

Comment: If, as the library writer, you already defined the variable, the user also defining it will cause a link-time error. That's why you, as a user, cannot define `std::cout`.

Comment: I would propose adding it as an additional argument to `calc`, with a default value... i.e. `void calc ( double* a, double* b, int r, int c, double (*f) (double), bool do_round=false )`; not as a static or global variable.

Comment: @twalberg And what if you don't want to add arguments or functions to your library? Is there any p\other way?

Comment: @TheGoodUser That's the nice thing about doing it that way - since it has a default value, existing calls to that function that don't specify that argument continue to compile without issue. Since the flag is intended to modify the behavior of a single function, that's really where it belongs, design-wise. Unless I misunderstood your description, and the flag actually affects more than just the semantics of a single function...

Comment: @twalberg you are totally right. But the problem is, the user program is written already. Our teacher wants us to implement this function with the same arguments I said in the question, and not any more/less argument. He also doesn't want to call another function to change this flag. He only want the library to work fine in the situation he initiate the `round` variable or not initiate it. (in the latter my library must set in false as default)